# Mysql / PHP upload null value into timestamp type attribute

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to upload a csv file into a Mysql database, using `php`.

The attribute/column name `closed` is type `timestamp` with default value of `Null`.

The file I am trying to upload has dates in these column, but some of them do not have dates in them, and appear as empty in the csv file.

These empty values need to be uploaded as the default `Null` into the `closed` column.

I am trying to upload with this:

```
INSERT INTO work_tickets(wt_id, wt_created, closed, client_id, agent_id)  
VALUES ('$wt_id', '$wt_created', '$closed', '$client_id', '$agent_id')
```

and have tried  ($client[21] is the date value):

```
    if (is_null($client[21])) {
        $closed = NULL;
    } else {
        $closed = $mysqli->real_escape_string($client[21]);
    }
```

and:

```
    if (empty($client[21])) {
        $closed = NULL;
    } else {
        $closed = $mysqli->real_escape_string($client[21]);
    }
```

and:

```
    if (empty($client[21])) {
        $closed = 'default';
    } else {
        $closed = $mysqli->real_escape_string($client[21]);
    }
```

and have also tried taking it as it is;

```
$closed = $mysqli->real_escape_string($client[21]);
```

But all of these the result is that the empty rows are not inserted.

How can I upload these so that they are inserted  `Null`?

Alternatively, I realize that it will revert to the default of null if I exclude the `$closed` value in the insert statement, but then I will be doing two insert statements?

edit: full php code:

```
<?php
//load the database configuration file
include 'config1.php';

if(isset($_POST['importSubmit'])){

    //validate whether uploaded file is a csv file
    $csvMimes = array('text/x-comma-separated-values', 'text/comma-separated-values', 'application/octet-stream', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/x-csv', 'text/x-csv', 'text/csv', 'application/csv', 'application/excel', 'application/vnd.msexcel', 'text/plain');
    if(!empty($_FILES['file']['name']) && in_array($_FILES['file']['type'],$csvMimes)){
        if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])){

            //open uploaded csv file with read only mode
            $csvFile = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "r");

            //skip first line
            fgetcsv($csvFile);

            //parse data from csv file line by line
            while(($client = fgetcsv($csvFile)) !== FALSE){


                $wt_id = $mysqli->real_escape_string($client[0]);
                $wt_created = $mysqli->real_escape_string($client[3]);
                $client_address = $mysqli->real_escape_string($client[4]);
                $prob_type = $mysqli->real_escape_string($client[6]);
                $prob_descr = $mysqli->real_escape_string($client[7]);
                $follow_up1 = $mysqli->real_escape_string($client[9]);
                $follow_up2 = $mysqli->real_escape_string($client[10]);
                $follow_up3 = $mysqli->real_escape_string($client[11]);
                $prior_stock_move = $mysqli->real_escape_string($client[20]);
                $client_id = $mysqli->real_escape_string($client[24]);

                // Timsestamp
                if (empty($client[21])) {
                    $closed = null;
                } else {
                    $closed = $mysqli->real_escape_string($client[21]);
                } 


                if (($client[26]) =='-') {
                    $agent_id = NULL;
                } else {
                    $agent_id = $mysqli->real_escape_string($client[26]);
                }  

                $wt_active = $mysqli->real_escape_string($client[27]);

                $query = $mysqli->query(
                "INSERT INTO work_tickets(wt_id, wt_created, client_address, prob_type, prob_descr, wt_active, follow_up1, follow_up2, follow_up3, prior_stock_move, closed, client_id, agent_id)  
                 VALUES ('$wt_id', '$wt_created', '$client_address', '$prob_type', '$prob_descr', '$wt_active', '$follow_up1', '$follow_up2', '$follow_up3', '$prior_stock_move', '$closed', '$client_id', '$agent_id')
                 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
                    wt_id='$wt_id' , wt_created='$wt_created', client_address = '$client_address', prob_type='$prob_type', prob_descr = '$prob_descr', wt_active = '$wt_active', follow_up1= '$follow_up1', follow_up2 = '$follow_up2', follow_up3 = '$follow_up3', prior_stock_move ='$prior_stock_move', closed = '$closed', client_id = '$client_id', agent_id = '$agent_id'
                ");

            }

            //close opened csv file

            fclose($csvFile);

            $qstring = '?status=succ';
        }else{

            $qstring = '?status=err';
        }
    }else{
        $qstring = '?status=invalid_file';
    }
}

//redirect to the listing page
header("Location: worktickets.php".$qstring);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the single quotes from $closed variable in your SQL statement.

```
INSERT INTO work_tickets
            (wt_id,
             wt_created,
             closed,
             client_id,
             agent_id)
VALUES      ('$wt_id',
             '$wt_created',
             $closed,
             '$client_id',
             '$agent_id')
```

After chatting a bit it turns out the query was invalid.  If you place your full SQL statement into a variable and echo it at the point of failure you will be able to visually determine quite quickly what the issue is.  Alternatively if you can't spot the issue you can run it directly in a SQL program (CLI / MySQL Workbench / other SQL tool).  Make sure the column types match with what your query has generated for the insert, you can also use [mysql_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) to assist.  Try coercing the $closed variable again by wrapping it to see if your error is different also. To clarify, this is a data issue.

Comment: What should $client be? (from options above.. ie Null?)

Comment: You can use empty (that should work).  Above solution will work for you as you are always coercing the variable closed.  If you mark correct (assuming it does work) as a bonus I'll edit with a more elegant way of doing.

Comment: I always set null variables to lowercase as it is prettier but NULL is fine also...

Comment: I've love to mark it as the answer, but when I use this method none of the rows are loaded, including the ones with valid dates.

Comment: When you say loaded do you mean inserted?  If so you need to post more code - in particular the logic to where the SQL execute gets called as this is most likely your issue.  Post the rest and we'll have a go at solving.  One issue is solved (the one of coercion).  Now it's a logic issue.

Comment: see edit for full php code.. $client[21] is the value of the timestamp attribute.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174335/discussion-between-cherrysoft-and-wazzahenry).